# Is it possible to change the shadow color (Generated from translationZ) from black to white

Tags: android

Currently, I have a card liked design as follow.

[image]

As you see, there's shadow around the card liked layout. It is implemented as follow. (I didn't use `CardView`, as it doesn't full-fill my other requirements)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/cardSelector"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/lift_up"
    android:clickable="true" >
    ...
</FrameLayout>
```

The shadow effect is caused by `lift_up.xml`. It is as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="4dip"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="2dip"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

---

As, I need to provide black theme in my app. I redesign the cards which look like.

[image]

Since the color of shadow is black, it is not visible under black theme.

I was wondering, is it possible for me to change the shadow to white? If yes, how? Thank you.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Sorry. I don't have any good solution.